# How do Reddit and similar sites keep users from voting on links and comments more than once?

Tags: voting, reddit

I was curious and downloaded the code but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. I thought I might find a database table with user ids mapped to link ids or comment ids. But I can't seem to find anything like this.

Answer (score 1):

This ticket points to some of the code involved: http://code.reddit.com/ticket/520